# CTRL + SPACE Shortcut Key for Context Menu on Mac

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, context-menu

I'm writing as a last resort after my many hours of searching....

My System is:

- Mac OS X 10.9.4
- Firefox 31.1.1
- Thunderbird 31.1.2

It seems I must be going about my goal to access the context menu with using my mouse the wrong way.

I've searched high and low to find a keyboard shortcut which reliably opens the context menu relative to the current text cursor position.

Now I feel I should repeat that again since I've found a few solutions using the addon keyconfig which successfully open the context menu, however they are not relative to the current cursor position.

For example: let's imagine I'm typing this message and make a spelling error, in previous version of Firefox I was able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger a context menu and select the correct spelling of the of the word at which my cursor currently resided.

I found this process incredibly useful as I was able to correct my spelling as I type without taking my hands off of the keyboard.

I've included my Thunderbird version as that is the proverbial straw that broke my back ;) Upon updating to Thunderbird 31.1.2 from 26 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> no longer works in Thunderbird either.

I'm sure this may sound silly to some, however I was quite fond of this functionality, enough so to have cumulatively spent endless hours scouring the Internet in the hopes of finding a solution....alas I've reached my wits end!

Could anyone kindly spare the time to help me with my request?

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but you can do this with Keyboard Maestro, at least back in version 5 (they're at version 6 now).

It's not obvious from this picture, but you can specify which "type" of mouse click: left, middle, or right.  I set this up w/ a right-click, and it works perfectly to open the contextual menu under the mouse cursor (not the "text cursor", if you know what I mean).

[image: Keyboard Maestro]

Comment: Thanks jimtut, Do you happen to use Thunderbird? Could you tell me if this works to show the relative suggestions to the current word you would be trying to correct?

Comment: I don't have it.  "KM" has a trial version though, so it doesn't hurt to give it a try.  It definitely works open up the CM for me in other apps.